# Java regexp: exact match from a given point at the middle of the input

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string on which I need to run several regexp patterns (some sort of a parser). When running these regexps I want to consider only a certain part of the string (from a given position until its end) *and* I want a pattern to match only if the match with input starts at the given position.

Let's assume the input string is `abcdefghij`, that the current position is `1`, and that I have these two patterns

- p1: `[b-d]+`
- p2: `[h-j]+`

Given that my position is `1` then I want `p1` to match and I want `p2` not to match (as `p2` matches the `hij` part of the input - that is: the match starts at position `7` and not at position `1`).

Using `Matcher.find(offset)` does not work as it does not require the match to start at the given position:

```
// Output: true (whereas I want it to be false)
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("[h-j]+").matcher("abcdefghij").find(1));
```

Note that adding a `^` to my patterns does not solve the problem:

```
// Output: false (whereas I want it to be true)
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("^[b-e]+").matcher("abcdefghij").find(1));
```

Other alternatives (that do not work):

(1) Applying `.substring()` on my input string (and adding `^` to ally my patterns) will work but the complexity of `.substring()` is O(n), which may be problematic for me (this is a library code that will be used on potentially large inputs which in ways that I cannot predict upfront)

(2) I can use the matcher's object `.start()` method to determine where the match occurred, as follows:

```
matcher = Pattern.compile("[h-j]+").matcher("abcdefghij");
System.out.println(matcher.find(1) && matcher.start() == 1);
```

My problem with that is that the regexp algorithm will run throughout the entire input string (which may be long) and only after it found a match the `matcher.start() == offset` condition will reject the match if it is not at the desired position.  Seems inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Matcher.lookingAt()` which anchors at the start but not the end (unlike `find` which doesn't anchor).

Specifically:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".....").matcher(input);
m.region(offset, input.length());
if (m.lookingAt()) { 
  ...
}
```